# Export blocks with features extra

Tags: blocks, features

I installed the Features extra module to export custom made blocks in my Drupal 7 environment. But for some reason, it doesn't work...

What I do is the following:

1. I create a custom block
2. I give it a machine name, description, title and body, just like it's required.
3. I go to `Structure - features - Create feature`
4. I create my feature by clicking the custom block under `FE Block`
5. The `fe_block` dependencies fills in automatically.
6. I download the feature and place it in `/sites/all/modules/features`
7. In my install profile I add this line: `dependencies[] = custom_blocks`
8. I try to reinstall the website and... nothing!

The blocks aren't showing up in my `Block`-page, but the feature is... What am I doing wrong in this process? Do I need to enable something or install an extra module in order to get my custom blocks exported?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

Use the **Panels** module to get the ability to create "*Mini-panels*" which function as equivalents to the standard Drupal block.

I believe there is much better support for exporting mini-panels into Features, since exportability was a key design component for the Panels module.

Personally, I've been successful using Panels, mini-panels, and Features.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can't put drupal blocks into features without patching it.

Have a look at the [Boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes) module, this is a replacement for the blocks system and is compatible with features.

> Boxes module is a reimplementation of the custom blocks (boxes) that the core block module provides. It is a proof of concept for what a re-worked block module could do.
>
> The module assumes that custom blocks are configuration, and not content. This means that it is a reasonable action to ask for all blocks at one time, this is in fact exactly what the core block module does.
>
> Boxes provides an inline interface for editing blocks, allowing you to change the contents of blocks without going to an admin page.
>
> Boxes provides exportables for its blocks via the (required) Chaos tools module. This allows modules to provide blocks in code that can be overwritten in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your [Features Extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_extra) module. Or try [Blockexport](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockexport) module instead.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need to enable your features.
Use drush, it's an interesting tools for drupal

> drush en your_feature_name.