# Exporting block settings in a Feature (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, blocks, features

I am trying to learn about creating a reasonable workflow between a development site and a production site and I have decided to use the Features module to help accomplish this task.

On my front page I have a couple blocks that display newly added and top rated content.  I have used features to export these views but I do not see anyway inside of the Features module to export my block settings.  I set the new projects and highest rated blocks to show up in the content section of a page. I filter it to only show up on the front-page inside the view.

How to export these block settings inside my feature so I do not need to reconfigure them on each site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can export much more using Feature together with [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) and [Features extra](http://drupal.org/project/features_extra).

***Strongarm*** gives site builders a way to override the default variable values that Drupal core and contributed modules ship with. It is not an end user tool, but a developer and site builder tool which provides an API and a limited UI.

***Features extra*** supports: vocabularies; nodequeues (definitions); block settings; custom blocks (boxes).

Additionally [UUID Features Integration](http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features) provides a mechanism for exporting content (nodes, taxonomy, fields) into a features module.

Comment: I would also recommend using drush and git to handle the workflow.

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I needed.  I was planning on getting git going once I figured out how to use features a little better.

Comment: Fantastic ! As Mike, that's just incredible !

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Boxes](https://drupal.org/project/boxes) module as per [Exporting of blocks for features](https://drupal.org/node/727266).

If you'd rather not install additional modules, and you're dealing with a Views block (where you simply need the block configuration settings), another option is to do this at the code level with a [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) implementation in a custom module's install file.  See below for an example.

```
/**
 * Configure block settings.
 */
function my_module_update_7101() {

  // Enable blocks
  db_update('block')
    ->fields(array(
      'status'     => 1,
      'region'     => 'content',
      'visibility' => 1,
      'pages'      => 'node/999',
      'title'      => 'My Block Title',
      'css'        => '',
      'js'         => '',
    ))
    ->condition('delta', 'BLOCK_ID')
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use [mini-panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) instead of custom blocks as been suggested [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15519/export-blocks-with-features-extra).  They work much the same, and panels appear to be better supported by features.  If you already plan to use panels, this also saves a few extra modules.